# How can I optionally override repository dependencies in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

Is it possible to optionally load a file like "WORKSPACE.user.bazel" from my main "WORKSPACE.bazel" file but only if that file exists?

I'd like to override certain dependencies during development only and not check in the WORKSPACE.user.bazel file.

Answer (score 2):

[`--override_repository`](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--override_repository) seems to do the job. See also [this](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5252).